# Facing this error while doing pip install in a python virtual env windows 10

Tags: python, ssl, pip

**This is the error I am getting after doing pip install flask in python virtual env**

WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting flask
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/flask/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/flask/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/flask/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/flask/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/flask/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/flask/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/flask/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for flask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). How can we help you with this? Are you asking for help with installation or are you asking for debugging an issue? Can you be more specific please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+pip+is+configured+with+locations+that+require+TLS%2FSSL%2C+however+the+ssl+module+in+Python+is+not+available

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting means that the SSL library is either missing in your virtualenv or it is broken. This issue is resolved by installing OpenSSL for Windows. The installation guide is [here](https://www.cloudinsidr.com/content/how-to-install-the-most-recent-version-of-openssl-on-windows-10-in-64-bit/).